# Laravel Application CRUD - Want to check wheather form data has modified

Tags: jquery, forms, laravel, validation, laravel-5.3

I want to process the data returned from edit form only if form data has modified. otherwise i want to show 'no data modified' message using toastr when submitting the form.

Comment: You can get the model from the database and test that against the data from the form.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to know if the model has been edited since it was queried from the database, or isn't saved at all, then you use the ->isDirty() function.

If you want to check if the model is dirty just call isDirty()

```
if($product->isDirty()){
// changes have been made
}
```

if you want to check a certain attribute:

```
if($product->isDirty('price')){
// price has changed
}
```

Comment: form data is in $request array.Before updating the model($role->update($request->all());), I want to make this check.how can i make use of this isDirty() function